# Mapping whole database to view Crystal Reports

Tags: database, mapping, crystal-reports-xi

Please let me know whether its correct or not?
I am mapping the whole database to view a report in which 
i have used the formula and parameter to filter and get the required report.

i mean there are 20+ table in database in which i need 7 main table to get
required fields to display the report - Is it advisable to map the whole 7 main table
in crystal report for viewing a report ?

Expecting your valuable reply 
regards,
Thiru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must map all the tables that have fields you use in your report UNLESS you are reaching those tables via a view or stored procedure. If you use a view or stored procedure to get data, then you can reference just those view(s) and/or stored procedure(s).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dylan, I like to know whether it will any performance issue if we map the whole db in crystal report or not. Because each time if we view the report, crystal report has to read whole DB (if we map whole DB) and filter the required table and rows - right.  I hope it will be some performance issue.  Am i right ?

Comment: Performance is affected by adding more tables/views/stored-procedures yes. It doesn't exactly "read [the] whole DB" but it does do things like set logon credentials and other operations more than if you had less objects. Honestly though, most performance issues are related to the actual complexity of the SQL that has to be run. For example, complicated joins, large stored procedures, etc. A lot of this is driven by how complex you make your report. If you run something like SQL profiler you can see how long the SQL for the report takes to complete.